# Can impact lift produce greater than 1 lift to drag ratio?

Tags: solar-sail, lift, drag

At orbital velocity in low circular Earth's orbit, at an altitude where mean free path exceeds cross sectional area of a craft or wing. *therefore aerodynamic lift becomes impossible* (Consider altitudes between: lowest set by China's Lixing-1 satellite (124x133km) and highest set by Kosmos-149 satellite (245x285km))

**Main question:** What is the maximum theoretical value of lift to drag ratio achievable with *impact lift* created by collisions with the individual atoms, rather than the aerodynamic lift? Can the lift/drag ratio ever be greater than 1?

If documented and known, is the angle of attack needed to achieve this maximum L/D ratio in such "slow speed" impact conditions (leo velocity) related in some way to the maximum "lift" to "drag" ratio angle of attack (or maximum transverse component) achievable by stellar sails, which is 35.26 degrees, at this time very fast impact velocities.